# JavaScript date comparison oddity

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with JavaScript date comparison.  I create a Date object for 31st Oct, and another for 1st Nov, yet getTime() for each returns the same figure, and the greater-than / less-than operators also consider the dates equal.  Here is my code:

```
d1 = new Date(2012, 10, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0);
d2 = new Date(2012, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
document.write(d1.getTime() + "<br />");
document.write(d2.getTime() + "<br />");
document.write((d1 < d2) + "<br />");
document.write((d1 > d2) + "<br />");
```

And here is the output:

```
1354320000000
1354320000000
false
false
```

The same code works fine around other month endings, it seems to be just these two dates that cause an issue.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Hint: months are zero based in JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

November (`10`) doesn't have 31 days, so it will wrap to December (`11`) 1st.

```
new Date(2012, 10, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0)
//Sat Dec 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)

//more wrapping:
new Date(2012, 10, 35, 0, 0, 0, 0)
//Wed Dec 05 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)
```

Comment: Many thanks, I had neglected to take the zero indexing of months into account.  Makes perfect sense now.